# Как добавить параметры запуска VBS?

Tags: vbscript

vbs запуск как-то так example.vbs -user1

при если user1
выдаёт

```
MsgBox"You are user1"
```

А при -user2

```
MsgBox"You are user1"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Скрипт:

```
MsgBox "You are " & mid(WScript.Arguments.Item(0),2)
```

Запуск

```
example.vbs -user1
```

Результат:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]